# My magic8ball code is not working on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def magic8ball(ctx, question):
    
  responses = ["It is certain.",
  "It is decidedly so.",
  "Without a doubt.",
  "Yes - definitely.",
  "You may rely on it.",
  "As I see it, yes.",
  "Most likely.",
  "Outlook good.",
  "Yes.",
  "Signs point to yes.",
  "Reply hazy, try again.",
  "Ask again later.",
  "Better not tell you now.",
  "Cannot predict now.",
  "Concentrate and ask again.",
  "Don't count on it.",
  "My reply is no.",
  "My sources say no.",
  "Outlook not so good.",
  "Very doubtful."]
      
  await ctx.reply(f"Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}")
```

Why is this not working?
There is no error for some reason...
and it does not send anything on discord
Anyone wanna help??

Comment: I have tested your code. Your code works, and a response does get sent by a bot. If you have other commands, do they work? Follow up question, do you have an `on_message` event that has processed commands?

Comment: i am using discord.ext commands

Comment: Do your other commands work?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).